# Network request failed in react native expo

Tags: laravel, api, react-native, expo

im using expo in react native.i have a problem when post data to api laravel.its say"Network Request Failed".heres my code:

i hope you can help me guys thankyou.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXGL3.png)

Comment: when i change localhost:800 with my ipv4 address in my laptop, its work but when i do res.text() it notif me that "the request url was not found this server"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your `fetch URL` is served using an HTTP endpoint. You can only make requests to HTTPS endpoints from react-native projects.

A possible workaround is to use ngrok. Just [download](https://ngrok.com/download) it and run:

```
./ngrok http 8000
```

Since your port number is 8000. It will expose an HTTPS endpoint and replace your `fetch URL` with that link and try fetching the data again