# Expo android network request failed

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I want to post a wav file(in blob) to my server.

I've tested my server using postman, and it works fine.

I also creat a react-app(web) and post the wav using the same logic below successfully.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', blob, 'test');

let requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
  mode:'no-cors',
};

// not localhost
fetch('http://xx.xx.xx.xx', requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

However I cannot even send the request out on my phone(Only got `[TypeError: Network request failed]` and my server didn't receive any request.)

I've been looking online and still not fix this issue. Please help.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62076086/network-request-failed-in-react-native-expo/62078052#62078052)

Answer (score 0):

It is not about the Blob, but more about the error you go.
So not sure if it can help...

I found out that I needed to put the Mime Type to match the file to upload.

```
formData.append('file', {
  uri : "file://...",
  name : "filename.mp4",
  type: "video/mp4",
});
```